# Business validation in JSON.Net

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

Consider we have a type describing results of participating in AB test

```
public class ABTest
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public ulong CountOfAs { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public ulong CountOfBs { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public ulong TotalCount { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SomeCustomTypeJsonConverter))]
    public SomeCustomType SomeOtherField { get; set; }

    [JsonModelValidation]
    public bool IsValid() => CountOfAs + CountOfBs == TotalCount; 
}
```

So each time instance of `ABTest` gets deserialized we want to validate that number of people in group A plus number of people in group B is equal to total number of people participated the test.

How can I express it in JSON.Net? External method doesn't fits well because this model may be found in any place of multiple hierarchies. Thus it can't be just deserialized and validated in two separate steps. Moreover,  I don't really have deserialized object in possibly invalid state so it should be part of default deserialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the object in a possibly invalid state then I'd first suggest making it immutable.

You can then use `JsonConstructor` for validation:

```
public class ABTest
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public ulong CountOfAs { get; }

    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public ulong CountOfBs { get; }

    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public ulong TotalCount { get; }

    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SomeCustomTypeJsonConverter))]
    public SomeCustomType SomeOtherField { get; set; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public ABTest(ulong countOfAs, ulong countOfBs, ulong totalCount, SomeCustomType someOtherField)
    {
        if (totalCount != countOfAs + countOfBs)
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(totalCount));

        CountOfAs = countOfAs;
        CountOfBs = countOfBs;
        TotalCount = totalCount;
        SomeOtherField = someOtherField;
    }
}
```

This gives you one single constructor that both Json.NET and the rest of your codebase can use for validation.

Comment: Looks nice. But what if I have more fields with custom serializators? See update

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: No problem; I edited it with the additional field just for completeness. Doing it this way won't affect how fields of other types are serialized.